# How to suppress #define locally?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Just caught a silly bug. I have a zip processing library with a `CreateFile()` function in it. `Winbase.h`, included somewhere deep in my headers, redefines it as `CreateFileW` and linker goes nuts.

Of course I will exclude `winbase` in this particular case. It just shouldn't be in the scope in the first place. But the theoretical question is still interesting,

Is there a way to suppress some defines locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the offending header file is ALWAYS the best solution for this (especially one as large as `windows.h` or `winbase.h` - they are included far too freely for my taste in many projects).

The only other solution is `#undef offending_symbol`.

Of course, another important thing is "do not use names that match the Windows/Linux system call names" - but `CreateFile` is a very obvious name for a function that creates a file, so I can see the temptation.

Comment: The "do not use names..." might be hard to accomplish, because taken seriously it should be "Do not use names that match OS API calls nor names that match calls to other often used APIs nor names that might become API calls some day..." ;-) Better stick to "only use thirdparty APIs in a small contained subset of your code".

Comment: Yes, I agree with both aspects of your comment. Some API names are very generic too, so it's hard to avoid colliding with them... And sticking system dependent code in a separate source file is DEFINITELY a good idea - also making porting to a different OS (or a different third party library, etc) much simpler.

Answer (score 5):

You can get around the macro by putting parentheses around the name:

```
(CreateFile)(arguments);
```

This works because the macro `CreateFile` is a function-like macro (i.e. it takes a list of arguments in parentheses); the right parenthesis after the name doesn't match the syntax for using a function-like macro, so the preprocessor does not expand it.

Of course, the "right" solution is to name the function properly, i.e., `create_file`. `<g>`

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor macros have no notion of C++ scope. `#define`s are just text replacements. If you want to have a 'local' `#define`, you do something like this:

```
#define CreateFileW CreateFile
... // here I can use the macro
#undef CreateFileW
```

Or in your case

```
#undef CreateFileW
... // Here the macro is not available
#define CreateFileW CreateFile
```

Answer (score 1):

There is

```
#undef
```

which removes defines (but nothing else).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the aforementioned `#undef` there technically is not much you can do against `#define`s, at least not portably.

The best way is to not use `#define` at all, or at least as little as possible and as constrained as possible. Sometimes you just need a macro to generate some boilerplate code a few times. Be sure to `#undef` that macro once you are done. The only other valid applications of `#define` I can think of are include guards and flags for conditional preprocessing.

For `#define`-deseases like the WinAPI headers you just should constrain them as much as possible. Don't use the `#define`d types of that API in your headers. You almost never want to use an API all over your application, so use it only in the cpps of a small layer around the API. Reducing the dependencies that way gives a lot more than just disinfecting the rest of your code.