# Why not include all the standard headers always?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I am reading Herb Sutter's `More Exceptional C++` and **item 37 on forward declarations** says:

> Never `#include` a header when a forward declaration will suffice.
>   Prefer to `#include` only `<iosfwd>` when the complete definition of a
>   stream is not needed.

Also I heard plenty of advice on including only the headers needed by the compilation unit to reduce dependencies.

I understand perfectly well why this should apply to **project** headers, but I do not quite understand why is it bad to include unnecessary **standard** headers.

For example I do something like this:

```
//standard_library.h

#ifndef STANDARD_LIBRARY
#define STANDARD_LIBRARY

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
...
// Everything I need in the project
#endif
```

and include this single header everywhere, where I need something from `std`

The problems that I can imagine are:

1. Pollution of namespace by C library functions that do not need to be in the std namespace.
2. Slower compilation time

But I haven't had significant problems with 1. sofar. Almost everything is in the std namespace. Also I do not fully understand why 2. is necessarily a significant problem. The standard headers rarely change. Also as far as I know the compiler can precompile them. When it comes to templates, they are instantiated(compiled) only when I need them.

There are also benefits:

1. Less typing
2. Less reading
3. Less figuring out which headers I need and in which header a certain function is

I am a beginner programer without experience on big projects and I sincerely want to figure this out so please have mercy upon me.

Comment: Let me tell you it makes a huge difference whether they're all precompiled or not.

Comment: You missed one problem: 3) unnecessary dependencies (a lot of them)

Comment: Well you've pointed out benefits and downfalls quite well. I guess the common agreement is that downfalls overweigh the benefits.

Comment: @juanchopanza Unnecessary dependencies are the premise. How much of a problem is it, really, given that all these headers are guaranteed to already be bundled with the compiler?

Comment: One other benefit I see is being able to more easily narrow down what belongs to which header.

Comment: @juanchopanza What do you mean by dependencies? Do you mean the fact that when one header changes everything needs to recompile, or something more?

Comment: Not only that. The fact that when you look at a file including your mega include-all header, you no longer know what is actually required. Unnecessary dependencies are just confusing.

Comment: You missed one benefit: doing this protects your code from the risk that it will not port to some platform where one standard header unexpectedly includes another.

Comment: @fizzer Other way around. The catch-all ensures safety of porting *from* a platform with internal dependencies to one without.

Comment: What about a platform that doesn't have one or more headers? :3

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I assumed your version is covered by OP's benefit 3.  But there's a risk in the other direction also.

Comment: @chris That platform is not a *C++* implementation, is it?

Comment: @ChristianRau, I'm constantly seeing people on here who can't use the whole standard library. I can't go into details from experience there.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Besides

- namespace pollution
- compilation time (although reducable by precompiled headers, it will hurt those compiling a large project once because they actually want to use it, and not develop - also you want to think about rebuilds which are necessary once in a while)

you named "Less figuring out which headers I need and in which header a certain function is" as a benefit. I agree so far as this can be true for well designed libraries and headers.

In practice however I experienced (at least with MFC/ATL) some errors which could be solved by   figuring out the correct order of includes. On the other hand one day you want to resolve an issue which makes you travel across the included headers - now imagine yourself looking at tons of headerfiles actually having nothing to do with your code file.

My conclusion is: The time you save by including a bunch of unnecessary headers do not pay off if you have to maintain a large project later on. The more time you invest before starting including any headers, the more time you will safe afterwards - but mostly without actually recognizing it.

Comment: Note, however, that "MFC/ATL" is **not** part of the C or C++ standard library.

Comment: Namespace pollution is IMHO, an implementation "bug"/"feature"/"annoyance", as all C++ headers should not pull anything into the global namespace.

Comment: @PeteBecker, you are correct of course - this was just one example which demonstrates that you can not rely on anyone (be it an indie developer or big corporation) playing by the rules. So you should not break them in the first place - we also know from "C-style C++ code" what arises if you just copy old habits: just because it works, does not mean it makes sense in the big picture.

Answer (score 3):

On your system, it might not cause much of a slowdown, but someone else might have a different experience.

In the long run, computers will continue to get faster, and compilers will continue to get more efficient. The time saved obsessing over header files is certainly less than the incremental time spent waiting for the compiler, in most small projects.

But (for an implementation that doesn't precompile or cache them) the cost will be multiplied across all the source files. This affects the speed of non-incremental builds.

So for a library used over many sources or distributed across different platforms, it might still be a good idea to cut things out every so often, and before making a public release.

Answer (score 3):

Oh! I know a good one.

I have one proprietary library for making nice zip archive files out of memory data. It was designed to be multiplatform, but apparently not tested well enough on every platform including Windows.

It works great on Linux and other POSIX systems but as I tried to adopt it in my project, I've stubled upon this: [How to suppress #define locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230205/how-to-suppress-define-locally)

Both the library and winbase.h (included via the most standart windows.h) has a CreateFile entity. And, as in winbase it's just a macros, compiler don't see any problem, unless you actually try to use CreateFile in your code.

So yes, keeping your namespace clean might be a good idea.

Comment: OP is referring to literally standard libraries, which are specified in the ISO 14882 Standard for C++. To be called a C++ platform, the development system must include them. Things which are merely common such as `windows.h` are not standard headers. You mention an interaction between a platform library and *your* library, but the standard library isn't in play.

Comment: `CreateFile` is arguably a bad name for your library. You should prefix it with the library name, or say what *type* of file you're creating (e.g. `CreateZipFile`).

Comment: @Mehrdad If he puts it in his own namespace, it should be fine. Microsoft is insane to define a macro with such a name.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, Microsoft is crazy to define macros with the names `min` and `max`. I've always known about that, though, so it hasn't bitten me much. What did bite hard was their stupid `near` and `far` macros when I chose those names for parameters for near and far clipping plane distances. It compiled and I completely forgot about near and far pointers :( That was a constructor along the lines of `Foo(float near, float far) : near_{near}, far_{far} {}`. Of course being defined as nothing, that compiles, and it was hard to figure out even after narrowing down to that constructor.

Comment: Microsoft is insane and so are lots of other code junkies which do not invest time in thinking about a good name for their functions and macros. So CreateFile makes a very good example of why keeping the namespace clean *and* finding good function names is important.

Comment: @Vash, I can't wait until modules hopefully become commonplace and one library's macros don't affect another's. I know Bjarne liked the idea of scoped macros as well.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Oh I think I misunderstood the problem -- I was assuming his code was C, didn't realize he was talking about C++. Interesting, +1.

Answer (score 1):

There is in principle nothing against it.

The only thing that will happen is that your compile times will increase, unless of course you create a precompiled header of that `standard_library.h`, in which case the impact will be minimal.

Note that most people prefer to minimize their header dependencies. This mostly applies to your own header files, in which case a small change in an unused, but included header in a source file may trigger an unnecessary recompile of said source file for no reason whatsoever, slowing down incremental builds a lot.

Comment: AAMOF the standard even considers adding aggregation headers http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2905.pdf so you can just include  <std-all>

Answer (score 1):

This advice is some 10 years old. And somewhat dated by now. The speed of computers is up hundredsfold, storage went from G to T, insane amount of memory is sitting around idle.

So advices from the past may degrade. You're on good track asking for reasons, and may be on better track if you eventually runs some experiments and make up your own opinion.

Herb's item is way more general than your question. C++ (somewhat unfortunately) uses a file (translation unit) model for compilation -- not a source code repositiory/database. (Those who tried Visual Age C++ of IBM know how coll that was. ;)  A consequence of that is that you pack together a lot of stuff. Include files are not one liners.

So when you need to include a header to have a single declaration of something, you happen 
to drag in lot of other things.

And those other things just to compile may drag in other stuff. And so on recursively. So if you can avoid the inclusion it saves not one but thousands of lines. and inclusion of maybe not one but a few dozen of files. A good way of economy.  Also rebuild will be needed when any of those files change, regardless of the changes are likely be irrelevant for your stuff.

Say your header uses pointers of 10 different classes. And you include all 10 headers defining them, instead of just prefixing the use with 'class'. It means any client that may only use a few really gets all ten dragged in as dependency.   Not economic. In a project I worked a few years ago gtk++ was used. The .cpp files had just few hundreds of lines, but the preprocessor output was 800k or over million lines. No kidding. 
Though you pay a price in small redundancy: the thing may be class today but be something else (say typedef to a template). The _fwd.h idea mitigates that, but it really just centralizes the redundancy.  In practice we seek some balance in tradeoffs.

But all these ideas do not apply to things that are "stable" *and* ubiquitously used. In projects that put std:: to heavy and natural use you can see  and many other headers included in every single source. Because they are used. And if some refactoring removed the last vector today it will likely grow back tomorrow.

Here the choice is really just on the "where" the inclusion happens, and economy works the other way around. Setting up a "common" header that is used by everything removes a lot of noise from other files.  Especially if the system have support for that case. In VS you have

- precompiled headers, that allow one time compile of the common material and share the result with the other TUs
- forced include, that allows your common header just specified in the project and not in source files
- property sheets, that you include in the project file instead of using those settings manually

With such support it may be perfectly feasible to put many, even most of standard headers in that common file, along with some using declarations for vector and other common names.

Those who say you drag in many names that may cause conflicts are right -- but at the same time they are wrong for practice, as eventually someone will include that extra header and if the conflict exist it will topple the boat.  Unless using std:: stuff is forbidden in a project I say it is just bad practice to reuse its common names for different purpose. Someone wants to check in code with his own class string and claims it is certainly distinct from std::string by the prefix, I call 'over my dead body'.   While for rare names it's no big deal to sort out an accident.

And what is good balance changes by projects and even inside projects as time passes.

Answer (score 1):

When a header changes, programs affected change.  Changed programs need to be tested.  Being selective minimized exposure and hence testing.

Answer (score 0):

> Slower compilation time

This is the main reason.

Even with precompiled headers the compiler has to do lots more work to include every single declaration in the standard library in every single translation unit of your project.

If you have a large project consisting of hundreds of files then the compiler will be invoked hundreds of times, and each invocation must reload the entire standard library into memory.

The compiler will use more memory to store all the declarations and will have to check against a larger set of names when doing name lookup (although a decent hash table implementation in the compiler should mean that doesn't significantly affect lookup time, only memory usage.)

Comment: My experience is that if you have say 50 files in the project, and create one precompiled header having the union of their includes, compilation time goes way down. figures like 30sec->8, 20->5.  And a few additonal includes in the common header is not really measurable.