# Is it good practice to always include the standard headers?

Tags: c, header, conventions

I read an answer on this site explaining why one shouldn't always include all (include-guarded) header files - slows down compilation time, pollutes the global namespace, etc.

But I'd like to ask specifically - is always including standard headers such as `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>` considered good or bad practice?

Why shouldn't I maintain a `stdheaders.h` file with `#include`s for all standard headers, and just include it everywhere? I think this might save me bugs where I'm using a function which I forgot to include the standard header for.

Specifically I would like to know what is considered standard practice in C development. Thank you

Comment: Only include what you use.

Comment: Why would it be a good practice to include them if you don't use them? Do you also always use `int i,j,k;` in all functions just in case?

Comment: Including more than you need increases compile time. Include every header needed for what you use, and nothing more.

Comment: If you use a function for which you did not include a header, and your compiler doesn't provide a diagnostic, you need stricter flags, not a megazord header.

Comment: But then having to go back, identify, edit, and rebuild when you miss one, increases programmer time significantly, say 20 seconds a time if it is not trivial, and potentially 1 new header dependency for every 50 lines of code, could add up to an hour a week, that's $50 per week per developer potentially. Also I have mentioned before the issue that we all rely on accidental system includes that will break with new library releases. One monolith header file for the system includes, a second one for your customer-facing API, and a third for the main internal components means the pain is reduced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not include all the standard headers always?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830134/why-not-include-all-the-standard-headers-always)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is for each source file, whether it is a .c file or .h file, to include only the headers it needs.  Doing so not only reduces compilation time but also serves to document the file's functionality.

Here are a few examples:

f1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_int(int i)
{
    printf("i=%d\n", i);
}
```

f2.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *safe_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p = malloc(size); 
    if (!p) exit(1);
    return p;
}
```

f3.c:

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

The file f1.c only includes stdio.h because it does I/O but no other functions.  Similarly, f2.c only includes stdlib.h because it uses functions defined there but does not use any I/O function, and f3.c doesn't include any headers because it doesn't need them.

If you think you've included unnecessary files, comment them out and compile with all warnings enabled to see which ones declare functions or variables you need.

Comment: Thanks for your input. A follow up question if I may: suppose file `a.c` depends on file `d.h` and also on file `j.h`. File `j.h` depends also on `d.h`. This means `a.c` doesn't have to include `d.h` directly - it's already included via `j.h`. When initialliy starting to write `a.c`, should it still explictly include `d.h`?

Comment: @AvivCohn If a.c has a direct dependency on d.h, it should include it.  That way things won't break unexpectedly if j.h removes the dependency on d.h.